# objects are not valid as a React child (object with keys {background})

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am following a ReactJS tutorial so I cant really figure it out myself what is wrong here.

This is full error message:
[image]

And this is the full React code where this error occurs:

const SliderTemplates = (props) => {
    let template = null;

```
const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    arrow: false,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
}

switch (props.type) {
    case ('featured'):
        template = props.data.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <div className={styles.featured_item}>
                        <div className={styles.featured_image}>
                            style={{
                                background:`url(../images/articles/${item.image})`
                            }}
                        </div>
                        <Link to={`/articles/${item.id}`}>
                        <div className={styles.featured_caption}>
                            {/* {item.title} */}
                            TEXT
                        </div>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })

        break;
    default:
        template = null;
}

return (
    <Slick {...settings}>
        {template}
    </Slick>
)
```

}

Comment: can you share complete class code

Comment: I think here template is not react object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong style attribute definition.
Style is not separate child of div, it is attribute of div
This is correct variant:

```
<div 
 className={styles.featured_image}
 style={{ background:`url(../images/articles/${item.image})`}}
>
</div>
```